# Unable to connect to MySQL on Windows 10: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, windows, connectivity, errors

I have MySQL server (only the server) installed and running on my Windows 10 computer. I tried to connect to the server with the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -pSql2017
mysql -u root
mysql --version
mysqladmin version
```

and I was prompted this error message for all of these commands:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here's the full error log in MySQL `.err` file:

```
2017-09-20T15:18:23.699613Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-09-20T15:18:23.701731Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-09-20T15:18:23.707749Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.18-log) starting as process 6636 ...
2017-09-20T15:18:23.783738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-09-20T15:18:23.783738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-20T15:18:23.783738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-09-20T15:18:23.784742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-20T15:18:23.784742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2017-09-20T15:18:23.793754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-20T15:18:23.799823Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-20T15:18:23.805014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2017-09-20T15:18:23.808432Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-20T15:18:23.865044Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.077993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-09-20T15:18:24.078581Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-09-20T15:18:24.149742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.163022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.163022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.164024Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-09-20T15:18:24.214921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 2536231
2017-09-20T15:18:24.216931Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-20T15:18:24.219944Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.259280Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170920 23:18:24
2017-09-20T15:18:24.274464Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-09-20T15:18:24.275124Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-09-20T15:18:24.276132Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-09-20T15:18:24.276132Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-09-20T15:18:24.276132Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-09-20T15:18:25.099827Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-09-20T15:18:25.100829Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-09-20T15:18:25.101832Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2017-09-20T15:18:25.103838Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:18:25.576820Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:18:34.666344Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:19:01.851333Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:21:36.055613Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'IvanHJC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:22:23.449607Z 6 [Note] Access denied for user 'IvanHJC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:22:53.725216Z 7 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:23:06.056348Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:23:21.419300Z 9 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:24:24.813967Z 10 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:24:42.385257Z 11 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:25:32.038167Z 12 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:28:06.325698Z 13 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:29:20.246074Z 14 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:30:01.293215Z 15 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:38:32.117437Z 16 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:40:11.696041Z 17 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:41:32.384416Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2017-09-20T15:41:32.384416Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2017-09-20T15:41:32.385415Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2017-09-20T15:41:32.385415Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2017-09-20T15:41:32.385415Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-09-20T15:41:32.386419Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-09-20T15:41:32.388425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.388425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.388425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.389426Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.389426Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.390428Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.390428Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.390428Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.391433Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.391433Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.391433Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.392434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.392434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.392434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.392434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.392434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.393469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.393469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.393469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.393469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.394475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.394475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.394475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.395474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.395474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.395474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.395474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.396480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.396480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.396480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.396480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.397479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.397479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.397479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.397479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.398485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.398485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.398485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-09-20T15:41:32.398485Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-09-20T15:41:32.399452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-09-20T15:41:32.499858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-20T15:41:32.506841Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170920 23:41:32
2017-09-20T15:41:33.452166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2536259
2017-09-20T15:41:33.454172Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-09-20T15:41:33.455175Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-09-20T15:41:33.455175Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-09-20T15:41:33.456177Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-09-20T15:41:33.456177Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-09-20T15:41:33.457179Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-09-20T15:41:33.474348Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2017-09-20T15:41:35.247770Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-09-20T15:41:35.247770Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-09-20T15:41:35.250776Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.18-log) starting as process 8936 ...
2017-09-20T15:41:35.259853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-09-20T15:41:35.259853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-20T15:41:35.259853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-09-20T15:41:35.260802Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-20T15:41:35.260802Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2017-09-20T15:41:35.261858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-20T15:41:35.261858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-20T15:41:35.266817Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2017-09-20T15:41:35.267819Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-20T15:41:35.311756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2017-09-20T15:41:35.608334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2017-09-20T15:41:35.923967Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2017-09-20T15:41:35.925975Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2536259
2017-09-20T15:41:35.927883Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-09-20T15:41:35.931109Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2536460
2017-09-20T15:41:35.931109Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2536469
2017-09-20T15:41:35.932972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2536469
2017-09-20T15:41:35.932972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-09-20T15:41:35.933977Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.169145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-09-20T15:41:36.170152Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-09-20T15:41:36.241805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.267136Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.268138Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.269139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-09-20T15:41:36.327117Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 2536469
2017-09-20T15:41:36.329071Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-20T15:41:36.329071Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.348335Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-09-20T15:41:36.349341Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-09-20T15:41:36.349341Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.350344Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-09-20T15:41:36.350344Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-09-20T15:41:36.357400Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170920 23:41:36
2017-09-20T15:41:36.377919Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-09-20T15:41:36.378420Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-09-20T15:41:36.379423Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2017-09-20T15:41:36.380425Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:41:36.404991Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:42:25.327337Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:42:36.940488Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T15:44:37.090231Z 6 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:50:56.569904Z 7 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2017-09-20T15:54:00.831423Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2017-09-20T15:54:00.832928Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2017-09-20T15:54:00.833935Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2017-09-20T15:54:00.836942Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2017-09-20T15:54:00.836942Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-09-20T15:54:00.837949Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-09-20T15:54:00.842965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.842965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.843960Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.843960Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.843960Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.844962Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.844962Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.844962Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.845965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.845965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.846969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.846969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.846969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.846969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.847972Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.847972Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.847972Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.848973Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.848973Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.848973Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.849978Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.849978Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.849978Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.850980Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.850980Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.850980Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.851982Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.851982Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.851982Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.852984Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.852984Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.854033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.854033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855040Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855040Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855040Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855993Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855993Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-09-20T15:54:00.855993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-09-20T15:54:00.856995Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-09-20T15:54:00.957606Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-20T15:54:00.967323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170920 23:54:00
2017-09-20T15:54:02.213019Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2536497
2017-09-20T15:54:02.215068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-09-20T15:54:02.215068Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-09-20T15:54:02.216074Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-09-20T15:54:02.216074Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-09-20T15:54:02.217061Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-09-20T15:54:02.217061Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-09-20T15:54:02.231534Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2017-09-20T15:54:02.650632Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-09-20T15:54:02.650632Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.653642Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.18-log) starting as process 4680 ...
2017-09-20T15:54:02.661662Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-09-20T15:54:02.662665Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-20T15:54:02.662665Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-09-20T15:54:02.662665Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-20T15:54:02.663668Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2017-09-20T15:54:02.664670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-20T15:54:02.664670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-20T15:54:02.669682Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2017-09-20T15:54:02.670686Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-09-20T15:54:02.701006Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.762689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-09-20T15:54:02.763692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-09-20T15:54:02.836069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.849686Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.850688Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.851691Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-09-20T15:54:02.903345Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 2536497
2017-09-20T15:54:02.905396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-20T15:54:02.906358Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.929893Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-09-20T15:54:02.931399Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-09-20T15:54:02.932402Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.932904Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-09-20T15:54:02.933404Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-09-20T15:54:02.934407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170920 23:54:02
2017-09-20T15:54:02.963486Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-09-20T15:54:02.964489Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-09-20T15:54:02.965499Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2017-09-20T15:54:02.965499Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:54:02.992562Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-09-20T15:54:40.683627Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-09-20T16:14:45.678743Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: You really ought to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to at least `128M`; the old default of `8M` is dangerously low.

Comment: Was this an upgrade?  If so, from what version?

Comment: Did you run mysql_upgrade?

Comment: Yes I tried to upgrade via MySQL installer and the version is 5.7 before and after the upgrade. But still it's no use to solve my problem. Should I just uninstall and reinstall it? @RickJames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the ampersand symbol `&` in Windows command shell. Initially I had set the root password to something like this `Hjc**2017xb&` unaware that `&` is a special character in Windows command shell that should be escaped with `^` when passed as an argument. So it prompts error when I connect with explicit password

```
mysql -u root -pHjc**2017xb&
```

but not with implicit password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

So you can also connect explicitly by escaping the `&` character

```
mysql -u root -pHjc**2017xb^&
```

Also the syntax of the following commands are incorrect and that's why they also prompt errors

```
mysql -u root (missing the -p)
mysqladmin version (missing the dash --)
```

Answer (score -1):

The command should be:

```
mysql -uroot -pSql2017
```

I've removed the space between `-u` and `root`

Comment: The space between `-u` and `root` is optional.  The spacing after `-p` is important.